# Sorting table rows according to an array with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
<table>
      <tr id="1">
          <td>bla</td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="2">
          <td>bla</td>
      </tr>

       <tr id="3">
          <td>bla</td>
      </tr>

      <tr id="4">
          <td>bla</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I also got an array according to which I should sort this table rows, say array goes something like

array= [3, 4, 1, 2];

Any tips or ideas how I can rearrange rows with jquery/javascript to match the array?

Comment: possible duplicate: [JQuery/Javascript Reordering rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600700/jquery-javascript-reordering-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append them again, in the order you need them to be in. When you call `.append` and the element is already visible it will be removed from its current location.

```
var order = [3,2,1,4];

$.each(order, function(){
  $("table").append($("#" + this));
})
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/nZ6HJ/

Comment: By far the simplest and most effective solution (assuming all row IDs are in the array). Using `$.each` to iterate a simple array is slightly overkill though, I'd use a simple `for` loop if performance is a concern.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Define "by far". Also, if re-ordering HTML table rows is the task, array loop performance is not the concern.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, I guess I didn't pay enough attention when reading your answer. But I'll defend my performance statement, just because you're carrying 10 elephants on your back doesn't mean that you have to carry 1 more unnecessarily - they will add up with time as your application grows. And I find a `for` loop more readable and it doesn't a create a closure unnecessarily either.

Comment: @Tomalak Oh I didn't see you deleted your answer already, it was perfectly clear and working.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté No, my answer was actually wrong, that's why I deleted it. Regarding your analogy: If reordering table rows is 10 elephants, the `$.each()` is an ant. You won't gain any performance to speak of from not using it.

Comment: You're right about DOM manipulation being much heavier than simple iteration, however calling a jQuery method passing a function callback for each item an array when you can simply iterate with a native `for` loop is a big fat ant which I'd surely smash to the ground.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Theoretically speaking, you're right. In practice, for a one-time iteration of 100 items, you'll have a hard time *measuring* the difference, let alone *noticing* it.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes you're right there. Sorry, I just pick up on the milliseconds way too often. `=]` There are countless jsperfs comparing regular `for` with `for in` loops which shows ~8x speed difference, let alone jQuery iteration. But in the end, those will process in the millions of OPs/sec.

Comment: Here goes the jsperf for whoever is interested - http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach-vs-each/26 (this one doesn't include `for in` though)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/32 does. Anyway, jQuery `.each()` is about 10% of the speed of a simple for loop. If I had 10,000 loop iterations to do, I would consider not to use jQuery. :)

Comment: @Tomalak oh thanks for the jsperf `=]` Yeah, sometimes I have to remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/akiqex/1/edit)*

```
for(i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  $('#'+array[i]).appendTo('table');
}
```